# I am trying to build a Blackjack exercise game but my function is not working properly

Tags: python

I am trying this coding exercise of building Blackjack. At the bottom, I have a function called compare() which is to decide who wins and who loses.

It only triggers "properly" as how I programmed it when the input "draw" is under an else statement. While as the current code as shown below, even if the user or the dealer meets or even exceeds the criteria inside my compare() function, it doesn't trigger unless I choose not to draw any further cards.

```
def compare(user, computer):
    if user == computer:
      return "Draw"
    elif computer == 0:
      return "You lose"
    elif user == 0:
      return "Your win"
    elif user > 21:
      return "You lose"
    elif computer > 21:
      return "You win"
    elif computer > user:
      return "You lose"
    else:
      if user > computer:
        return "You win"


game_over = False
while not game_over:
  user_sum = calculate_score(user_cards)
  computer_sum = calculate_score(computer_cards)
  print(f"User cards: {user_cards}. Total: {user_sum}")
  print(f"Computer card: {computer_cards[0]}.")    
  
  if user_sum == 0 or computer_sum == 0 or user_sum > 21 :
    game_over = True
    
  draw = input("Do you want to draw another card? y or n: ").lower()
  if draw == 'y':
    game_over = False
    user_cards.append(deal_card())
  else:
    game_over = True

while computer_sum < 17:
    computer_cards.append(deal_card())
    computer_sum = calculate_score(computer_cards)
  
print(f"User final cards: {user_cards}. Total: {user_sum}")
print(f"Computer final cards: {computer_cards}. Total: {computer_sum}")
print(compare(user = user_sum, computer = computer_sum))
```

Comment: Can you show this function?

Comment: Hi, I already edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: what error or problem are you getting

Comment: @iamtrappedman Hi, not so much an error but just the function works differently. When the line of code " draw = input("Do you want to draw another card? y or n: ").lower()" is not within an else or elif statement, the function compare() only triggers when I input "n", while if the line of code is within an else or elif only then it works properly as intended.

Comment: because you have not specified what it should do when none of the conditions are met.

Comment: check the last `if` condition. there is no `else` there. what should function return when that `if` condition is not met ?